# Can I define methods for properties on a Swift class like in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, properties

Is it possible to define a method for a property on a Swift class

For example, I have a class named Test in Objective-C, and this class has one property called `testProperty` of `NSString` type

Test.h

```
@interface Test : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *testProperty;

@end
```

I define a getter method in the implementation for this property:

Test.m

```
#import "Test.h"

@implementation Test

-(NSString*)testProperty
{
    return @"testing property like method";
}

@end
```

How can I do the same in Swift? If make the class in Swift,

```
import UIKit

class Test: NSObject {
    var testProperty : String?

    func testProperty() -> String {
       return "testing property like method"
    }

}
```

then I receive an error:

> "Invalid redeclaration of testProperty()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called `Computed properties`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Example

```
var testProperty: String {
    return "testing property like method"
}
```

Subclass

```
class ClassA: NSObject {
    var testProperty: String {
        return "This is Class A"
    }
}

class ClassB: ClassA {
    override var testProperty: String {
        return "This is Class B"
    }
}

let test = ClassB()
print(test.testPropery) // prints "This is Class B"
```

Comment: So, if I have a class with defined property, I can't implement a method in a subclass to return a modification of this property?

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope that is the answer to what you mean.

Comment: Yes you did answer my question but my problem still remain, because the property that I need modify is an stored property of super class, so I will mark as accepted